# Website content looking too big on my laptop screen

Tags: windows, layout, resolution, screen-resolution

I'm developing a React project in Windows 10 and the issue I've come across is that my website design looks too big(when on 100% resolution of Chrome) on my laptop screen and works fine on 75%, I guess it's rendering the design of large screens on my laptop. Please guide me how to get rid of this problem and view the website in normal mode.
I've set my Window's `Scale and Layout as 150%(Recommended)`, and `Resolution of 1920 * 1800(Recommended)`, but when I view my website in the Chrome inspect tool at the dimension of 1920, it seems fine but when I view it in normal mode, then it content becomes so bigger.

**Note:** You might say that it's due to 150% but I've also checked by decreasing this, it decreases all the other content on screen but website looks same.
Please note that Chrome's resolution and Window's layout are two different things mentioned above,
first one is set to 100% and the second is 150%.